# ¿Cómo puedo enviar archivos por parametros a una funcion? en C++

Tags: c++

Buenas noches a todos,

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en c++ que utiliza funciones y archivos. Mi consulta es dentro, del main principal yo creé un archivo (lo hice dentro del main y no dentro de la función porque se usa para varias funciones) y debo pasarlo como parametro a una funcion llamada INGRESAR para que en ella (como su nombre lo dice) ingrese los datos en ese archivo. Y en otra funcion debo pasarlo igual como parámetro para que solo me muestre los datos. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? me tira este error

> error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]'|

Esto pasa cuando llamo la función dentro del main.

Gracias a todos

Comment: No deberías pasar por copia un `stream`. Pásalo por referencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si consultamos la [documentación del flujo de salida de datos a archivo](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) (`ofstream` → `o`utput `f`ile `stream`) nos indica lo siguiente:

> *The copy-constructor is deleted: this class is not copyable.*

La clase no es copiable. Probablemente tienes funciones así:

```
void INGRESAR(std::ofstream archivo);
```

Cuando en realidad deberías tener funciones así:

```
void INGRESAR(std::ofstream &archivo);
//                          ^ <--- Referencia a flujo de salida de datos a archivo.
```

Si pasas el flujo de salida de datos a archivo como referencia, evitas la copia y en consecuencia evitas el error.